# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.6

I try to connect 2 database in my `Laravel 5.6` project, but i got error like this

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (SQL: select * from `mt_merchant`)

**I tried following code:**

`.env`

**1st db connection (this is in my local server)**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thedaldb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**2nd db connection (this is in live server IP 18.188.209.59)**

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND= 18.188.209.59
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=delivery_test_copied
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=testuser
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=testuser@123
```

`app/config/database.php`

```
'connections' => [
    'onlineorder' => [
            'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND'),
        ],
]
```

`app/Models/OnlineOrder/OnlineOrder.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\OnlineOrder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OnlineOrder extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'onlineorder';

}
```

`app/Http/Controllers/Onlineorder/AppOnlineOrderController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Onlineorder;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Models\OnlineOrder\OnlineOrder;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Validator;
use Config;
use File;
use DB;


class AppOnlineOrderController extends Controller
{
    public function test($merchant_id)
    {
        $db_ext = DB::connection('onlineorder');
        $merchant = $db_ext->table('mt_merchant')->get(); //mt_merchant is table name
        print_r($db_ext);exit;
    }
}
```

> Simply i want to connect live server database in my local sever project

Comment: Is the live database open to remote requests?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson:  Yes

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I think `DB_PORT_SECOND` is the issue. I try to connect `local sever` also but same error.

Comment: 3306 is the standard port for MySQL. If that is the issue, then the server isn't using the standard port and you need to find out which to use. You should also try and connect to the remote database from something like MySQL Workbench (or any other DB-management application) to see if you can connect to it that way.

Comment: ...also, I hope that this isn't the actual IP, username and password (blank) to your live database? If it is and it is open, then you've just given total access to anyone that reads this post.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Yes just now am adding username & password and clear cache using `php artisan cache:clear` same error : (

Comment: You should _not_ write your actual credentials here. Did you try what I asked? Try and connect to the database from some other application to make sure it actually is accepting remote connections? Start with that... if that don't work, then it's a configuration issue and not a code issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187482/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried in work bench it connecting

Answer (score 1):

IP address always changes during time ... instead of using directed IP use main domain
like :

```
DB_HOST_SECOND=mydomain.com.sd
```

i think this will do

Answer (score 0):

At the "Connectivty and Security" of your RDS instance page check if the configuration have "Public Accesibility" on "Yes" option. Maybe you don't have a public IP associated to your instance.

[image: Public Accesibility]

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/